# Upload speed much higher than download speed:

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, speed

On Pc, downloading speed is much lower than uploading speed. But on the same router, same wireless network other devices have downloading speed greater than uploading speed

- Speed test by ookla on windows pc:
  [speed test on win10 laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaXnw.jpg)

  1. Download speed: 13.54 mbps
  2. Upload speed: 53.50 mbps
- Speed test by ookla on android phone:
  [speed test on android phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXhVJ.jpg)

  1. Download speed: 33.66 mbps
  2. Upload speed: 27.73 mbps

There are no throttling(QoS) setting present on router. Also no speed limiter application on windows laptop. So, why downloading speed is lower on windows laptop?

Comment: Are you using WIFI?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: It could be a firmware issue on the computer, or the positioning of the device. Try upgrading the wifi driver and moving it closer to the AP and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the solution.
Problem is with Dell laptop softwares.

Permanantly disable following services:-

1. SmartByte network service
2. Rivet Dynamic Bandwidth Management

To disable these services, search for services.msc and find respective services and open their properties tab. Now first stop those running services and then disable them.

Voila. Now my download and upload speed at 50 mbps.